# Dynamic scale bar, coordinates and grid for map frame in Mapinfo map layout

Tags: mapinfo, coordinates, scale, layouts

I am looking for a **dynamic scale bar** and **coordinates (grid) for map frame** in the map layout of Mapinfo.

To make it clear I am talking about separate scale bar in layout which is not part of map frame. Of course with possibility to have it automatically connected with map frame so when the change of map is made it also redraw the scale bar and coordinates around map frame (and/or grid).

But I don't see these options anywhere and after some searching it seems it is possible to do it simply and dynamic only with extension tool like Encom Discover.

Am I missing something?

**1. Dynamic Graphic scale bar**

*In MapInfo Professional version 10.0 you can create a dynamic scale bar as part of your map.*

Close, **but**... I don't want it as part of map window, I want it separate. Only thing which come to my mind is make the map frame bigger containing the place where I want scale bar and mask the rest around with white rectangles.

Any better idea for separate dynamic Graphic scale bar?

**2. Coordinates and grid for map frame**

*- no default solution*

*- free mapbasic tool - from J.Wilcock called Layout Coordinate Grid* - very close - allows to draw grid lines and place coordinates around frame. But it is not dynamic, also settings are basic, not many options, maybe having source code, it would be possible to extend it. At least for few more options and possibility to delete all lines and texts at once (again no group function for objects in layout) for redrawing.

Do you know any better way or free tool for coordinates and grid for map frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am closing this one because Mapinfo does not seem to have anything better.

The best way for me to do this is by using QGIS or ArcMap - both have very good tools for Dynamic scale bar and grid for map frame in layout.